# Try Catch Query Powershell

Tags: powershell

Can anyone advise why when I run this script I still get a generic error generated by powershell? It is nested in an IF statement originally.

try {

Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" -Force -Recurse | Out-Null

} catch { "Appdata Cache does not exist!"

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch` only works on terminating errors. So you’ll have to change your `try` statement to. Also you’re missing a “\” in your path

```
Try{

    Remove-Item C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop

}Catch{

    “Appdata cache doesn’t exist”

}
```

Also `Remove-Item` doesn’t return an object so you don’t need to redirect it to `null`

Comment: Would it work in this context too? try {

Remove-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\ -Force -Recurse | Out-Null

New-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\ -Force | Out-Null

} catch {

Remove-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\ -Force -Recurse | Out-Null

New-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\ -Force | Out-Null

}

Comment: Basically trying the 15.0 values, if this errors, use the 16.0 values.